# Help identify this mite?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

I saw a decimal-sized dot walking on my hand. I wanted to know what this is, so I got it onto some paper and sandwiched below a piece of clear tape so I could keep it in place and photograph it. However it's so small that even with my camera lens almost touching the specimen, I can't get a great photo. It's small, about 0.8mm long, beige or gray or brown with a pattern on the back. It's a little smooshed from the tape so it's hard to tell if it has 6 or 8 legs and is an insect or an arachnid. But hopefully based on the shape, size, and pattern it can be identified.

Location is southern California.

[image: smallspider]

[image: smallspider]

**Update**: I now believe this to be a rat mite or bird mite. I'll include some additional photos that were better quality (photos were taken with a close-focus camera, mites were on printer paper underneath Scotch tape, back-lit by an LED light):

[image: rat mite, with ruler for scale]

[image: rat mite, partially fed]

[image: rat mite]

[image: rat mite, unfed]

[image: rat mite, fed]

[image: rat mite, unfed]

Comment: @theforestecologist I updated it again with a few more photos.

Comment: Related: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85319/16866), [Tiny white very hard cell bug! Please help to identify!](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82421/16866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bird mite (or possibly rat mite) in the genus *Ornithonyssus* of the parasitic family [Macronyssidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macronyssidae).

[image]

<sup>Credit: user Aewills on [bugguide.com](https://bugguide.net/node/view/690531)</sup>

Distinguishing between species is difficult.

In fact, according to [idtools.org](https://idtools.org/id/mites/invasive_mite/Invasive_Mite_Identification/key/Mesostigmata/Media/Html/100Introduction.htm), identification of Mesostigmata to family or lower can usually only be accomplished if the specimen is an adult female.

[Blaine Mathison](https://bugguide.net/user/view/33710) mentions the following features useful for identifying these mites to lower taxonomic levels under magnification [source: [bugguide.com](https://bugguide.net/node/view/683544)]:

- chelicerae shape
- dorsal plate breadth and degree of dorsal coverage
- spiracle present between legs
- genitoventral plate width
- sternal plate shape and presence of setae

You can find existing answers to posts about bird mites on Biology.Stackexchange below:

- [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85319/16866)
- [Tiny white very hard cell bug! Please help to identify!](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82421/16866)

Answer (score -1):

It could be a tick nymph. Difficult to tell as you can't see the beak and the front legs very well. Check out this tick identification site:

http://www.tickencounter.org/tick_identification/tick_species

Looks most like the dog tick maybe?

Comment: Thanks. Actually it turned out to probably be a mite, probably a rat mite. I found many more which appeared to be coming from the attic where we have had rats, and when I took more macros they did appear to look like rat or bird mites. I just never got around to updating this with the new info and photos.