# Unable to identify bug/insect in house

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I am not able to identify this bug/insect. 
I stay in Dubai and have been noticing this bug/insect in my apartment since a week now. It is so tiny that it's difficult to notice. The image below has been taken using a DSLR by placing it on a book page and cropped to more than 100% zoom.

I don't know the source, can feel it crawling on my skin and that's the only way to see it. One good thing is it cannot fly.

I went through all the questions about insect identification, but couldn't find any closest match for this. I also compared it to a book lice, but it's nowhere near to it.

I suspect it bites and leaves the skin itching with red spots similar to a mosquito bite.
Does anyone know about this bug if it is harmful, and how to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Hmm not a great picture. How small would you say it is? Do you have any pets or animals in the home? More importantly, do you have birds living in/on your home or any rodent probems?

Comment: Possibly related: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85319/16866)

Comment: @theforestecologist - Bingo! Thanks for the link. It is indeed nearest match to a Bird Mite. We don't have birds, animals or any pets at home. However, pigeons often visit our balcony just to be shooed away by us. Now will need to see how to prevent them from coming. Please post this as an answer, so I can mark it.