# What is this very small black bug?

Tags: species-identification

I saw a very tiny black bug crawling over my computer screen the other day. Having recently acquired a "[fingertip microscope](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1289187249/imicro-q2-an-800x-fingertip-microscope-for-any-smart-phone)" for smartphone, I started investigating.

On a white paper it seemed like a small black dot. I think its in the 0.3 - 0.8 millimeter range.
It would have been fairly unnoticeable if it weren't for it to crawl over my screen.

What could it be? I was thinking about dust mites, but they say it should appear as white. So I'm not entirely sure.

I live in Western Europe.

```
Note: don't look at the scale. It is wrong.
```

[image: they seem to have 8 legs]
[image]

Comment: Also related: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/85321/16866)