# Does anyone know what kind of bug is this?

Tags: species-identification

i found these tiny little bugs today all over my windowsill, the walls around the window, and on my chargers in the plugin[image] near the window. they’re like microscopic i can’t even see them. i used a spider and ants spray to kill them, it’s all i had for now. i’ve also been cleaning and wiping my walls down but there’s still a few left. i’m scared they’ll all come back again by tomorrow. does anyone know what they are and how i can get rid of them?
[image]

Comment: Welcome ca.bus. Could you tell us where in the world you are, what if anything is visible that they might view as a food source. Looks to me like a type of thrip instar, but more info needed, and ID isn't easy anyhow. A close-up picture from on top and another from the side would help if you can get them. Use the [edit] facility to add detail.

Comment: Likely related (but awaiting better picture to confirm) : https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/85321/16866

Comment: any shipping plans? (asking for a friend)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [mite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mite): it has eight short legs and only one body part (in comparison to spiders, which have two body parts). No idea which order or even species though.

Here is an [article about indoor mites](http://www.idph.state.il.us/envhealth/pcmites.htm) - maybe "yours" is among them - with some recommendations to manage them.