# What are these little bugs?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology, invertebrates

I recently found at least 50 of these little bugs roaming around my window  sills indoors in my bedroom right behind the head of my bed. I can’t seem to find what they are. I’d love tips on what they are or how to get rid of them. They’re extremely small probably no larger than 1 mm. I tried vacuuming them away but I still see plenty of them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bio-SE! Where is your window sill located? We require a where and when component to all species-ID questions. A size estimate and slightly better pictures would also be useful.

Comment: Related: [Help identify this mite?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58636), [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85319/16866), [Tiny white very hard cell bug! Please help to identify!](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82421/16866)

Answer (score 1):

These are very likely [mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acari) (notice their small size and 8 legs). Based on their size, appearance, and abundance, I'd guess they're bird mites (family [Macronyssidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macronyssidae)). Since they're near your window, I assume you either have a bird nest outside your window or frequent bird visitors to your window.

[image]

<sup>Credit: user Aewills on [bugguide.com](https://bugguide.net/node/view/690531)</sup>

you can find existing posts about bird mites on Bio.Stackexchange below:

- [Help identify this mite?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58636)
- [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85319/16866)
- [Tiny white very hard cell bug! Please help to identify!](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82421/16866)